# com.ibm.wsspi.http.channel.exception.WriteBeyondContentLengthException

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a war file deployed in webshpere liberty profile server.

First time when I put the file in the `/wlp/usr/servers/MyApp/apps`, it ran fine. But after making some changes, I again replaced the old war file with the new file. After that, I started getting `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` error for some files.

When I tried to load the file separately from my browser, I got this error: `Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.ibm.wsspi.http.channel.exception.WriteBeyondContentLengthException`.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any fix to this problem in the [official documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI12194). Hence I applied a workaround.

I first commented out the entry of the app in `server.xml`. Then I again uncommented it. This way, the server had to recalculate all the size of the files from scratch.